# Understanding company income statements: What is a good profit margin that would make it worthwhile to invest?

Tags: stock-analysis, margin, profitability, income-statement

I have been learning about how to read and understand a stock company's income statement and using those variables to determine the worth of the stock. My question is, what is a good profit margin for a company that would make it worthwhile to invest, 5%? And what are the most important indicators to look at when making decision's based on the company's fundamentals.

Comment: Check for how sustainable is the profit rather than numbers only.

Comment: Also note that you can't just look at margin and earnings and other features of the business. Investment is buying future-money with present-money, so you need to look at the price you're paying. For example: right now, Apple is trading for $360/share. Good deal? Beats me - but! all else being equal, it'd be a much better deal at $180/share and a much worse deal at $720. This is why the P/E ratio is still such a big deal, for all that earnings statements can be manipulated. (That said, looking at margins is still a very good idea.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is that it depends on the industry.

- **Retail:** usually have low margins, 3-5% being a goodish range; some of the value traders can be even lower.  Margin here is nothing compared to volume.  If you're selling bags of potatoes and making a 2% margin, that's fantastic as long as you can use the income from the potatoes you sold five minutes ago to buy the potatoes you'll sell in the next five minutes.
- **Manufacturing:** margins tend to be higher on specialised, high-end goods and lower on mass-produced, highly-competitive goods; could be anywhere from 5-20%.
- **Mining/Extraction:** oil, coal, gold, you name it, usually very good margins but nailed by high tax rates and the globally set prices, so some sources only good at certain price points.  A well-managed company will manage these fluctuations. Margins can be from 25-90%.
- **Services:** amongst the highest margins but often the most likely to suffer incredible crashes since competition is fierce and barriers to entry low. Margins usually around 40-60%.

In other words, margin alone - even in comparison to peers - will not be a sufficient index to track company success.  I'll mention Apple quickly as a special case that has managed to charge a premium margin for a mass-market product.  Few companies can achieve this.

As with all investment analysis, you need to have a very clear understanding of the industry (i.e. what is "normal" for debt/equity/gearing/margin/cash-on-hand) as well as of the barriers-to-entry which competitors face.

A higher-than-normal margin may swiftly be undermined by competitors (Apple aside).  Any company offering perpetual above-the-odds returns may just be a Ponzi scheme (Bernie Maddof, etc.).  More important than high-margins or high-profits over some short-term track is consistency of approach, an ability to whether adverse cyclical events, and deep investment in continuity (i.e. the entire company doesn't come to a grinding halt when a crucial staff-member retires).

Comment: And the margin and the reason for the margin might vary from year to year for a company.  Did they cut costs, or did they sell more?

Comment: Yeah, including, "Did they just lay off half their staff to achieve a quick margin boost?"